# React native release building at iOS error

Tags: ios, react-native

Sorry, but I hate *pple. I have many reasons, and it is one of them. Debug version works fine even without any critical warnings, but release crashes at some screens

P.S.

- XCode version 12.5
- React-native 0.65.1

[image]

Comment: If you're confident with your code + debug version 100% works. You could clean your xcode build + remove derived data. Then retry to deploy a Release version again.

Comment: i tried to clean build folder and test results. Did not help:(

Comment: Also I find what is "derived data" and clean it, but it's no effect

Answer (score 0):

Step by step commenting and redeploying helped me to find the root of this trouble. Now, I know, but I can't understand why, you I can't pass custom methods to Array.prototype or Object.prototype. It worked with debug version without any troubles, but release didn't :(